# Converting UTC date to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am having a date in isoUtc format and I want to convert it into mm/dd/yyyy format. I tried to use [the hint given in this blog entry](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) but the problem I am facing is that if I convert `2007-04-06T00:00Z` it gives different dates when user time zone is different. I want that it should give `04/06/2007` always independent of the user timezone.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you try this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hNctw/2/)

Comment: @InviS yes it is coming from a json string

Comment: @adeneo yes I tried this way but problem is if I change my time zone to ESt, then it gives a different date and if I change it IST then it is differtent

Comment: Then just use the string, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hNctw/3/)

Comment: for a date object: `var parts = d.split("T")[0].split("-"),date = new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parseInt(parts[2],10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var d = '2007-04-06T00:00Z';
var d2 = d.substring(5,7)+'/'+d.substring(8,10)+'/'+d.substring(0,4);
// outputs 04/06/2007
```

Comment: aaaahhhhh, it didnt striked my mind. Great, Thankyou for your help :)

Comment: Is there a way to convert this UTC string `var inputStr="Wed Dec 11 00:00:00 UTC 2013";`  to `dd/mm/yyyy` string?, i.e 11/12/2013

Answer (score 0):

You could thy this, if you have always constant format:

```
var dateString = '2007-04-06T00:00Z',
    dateRegExp = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2})/,
    match = dateString.match(dateRegExp),
    date;

if (match) {
  date = new Date(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3], match[4], match[5]);

  console.log(date);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/axufoj/1/edit)

Comment: Thankyou for the quick help, but with this I am not getting the dateformat to be mm/dd/yyyy